# 2 VMDK's for ESXi 6.7U2 Windows Server 2019 VM

Tags: windows, vmware-esxi, windows-server-2019

I am running ESXi 6.7 U2 with a Windows Server 2019 VM.

In my Datastore I have 2 100GB VMDKs, both of which are currently mounted in the VM. If I remove one, the OS will not start, doesn't matter which one I remove.

The problem I am having is; I did not create that second harddrive that is attached. Unsure how it was created and mounted. This is a problem, because I cannot remove one without the entire OS going haywire, even though according to Windows, that drive is completely empty.

Attached is an image of what is seen in Windows Disk Management, and I have tried to mount the EFI partition and take ownership, however it is saying it is an insecure filesystem. And will not allow me to take ownership.

I cannot right click the partition, as every option is greyed out. And I am hesitant to delete it using DISKPART, because when I dismount the harddrive the entire OS will not boot.

My assumption currently is that when installing the OS initially, it has split the EFI partition, and the actual C volume to separate VMDKs and mounted both in ESXi, however I am unsure how this would have happened.

I have checked and there is not snapshot through ESXi or anything of that nature.

[image: Image Link]

Comment: Could you provide a list of the files in the directory of the VM on your datastore (filenames and sizes)?

Comment: If those really are independent VMDKs my guess would be that the two disks where created by accident when the VM was created, and during the installation Windows installed the EFI partition on one disk, and the system partition on the other. I don't think you will be able to repair this without reinstalling windows.

Comment: It might be possible to boot from a livecd, shrink the system partition, create a new EFI partition in front of it and then boot from a Windows installation medium and use the boot repair functions. But IMO it would be easier to just reinstall Windows, since you already have a separate data disk.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delay in responding to any requests and so on.

Thank you everyone for the responses.
I worked out the issue, unsure if this was a mistake on my part, however I created a VM with the same name as the original VM (Which was a Ubuntu VM).

However I believe I neglected to delete the original file(s), which mean it kept the 100GB VMDK for Linux, and when I switched over to Windows, it mounted the VMDK as well, and installed the EFI partition on the Linux disk, and the rest of the system files on the VMDK created with Windows. Unsure if this was because windows auto-detected another boot loader on the drive prior. Unsure.

However, I am going to just migrate data doing some SATA passthrough and create a new VM migrating back to UbuntuServer and keeping a fresh install of Windows Server for testing and so on.

WHWL? (What have we learned?):

1. Do not create VMs with the same name unless you are ready to delete the data from the previous VM.
2. Check ensure OS has installed correctly before rushing into the setup of my Homelab...
3. Probably some other things I am too tired to realise at 4:17 AM.